# Can't run Spyder on Linux Manjaro

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, spyder, manjaro

I recently installed Anaconda from their official site. My operating system is Linux Manjaro, fully update. While trying to load spyder writing ***spyder*** in terminal I get this, as an output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/jakub/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I fully updated anaconda and anaconda metadata.
The version of python that I installed (on purpose) is 3.5.
Couldn't find an answer on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Their is an open issue in the Spyder github : https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3383. it look similar than your problem.

You can still install Spyder and PyQt5 with pip instead of with Anaconda/Miniconda. However, that has its problems too, like https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3520.

Or maybe try to install everything in your project virtualenv... I don't know if it will be better but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem once but got around it.

Instead of installing the one from the anaconda website, I used the one from the **AUR** (Arch User Repository). Basically what installing from AUR does is that it automatically installs dependencies before actually installing the main software.

AUR Anaconda Link: [Click Here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/anaconda)

To use AUR you can use either yaourt, pamac etc.

Steps for yaourt.

1.Go to terminal and type: sudo pacman -Sy yaourt

2.Then type: yaourt anaconda

3.Select the anaconda package number and follow the instructions.

For Pamac.

1. Go to options an enable AUR search.

2. Search for anaconda

3.Follow along the instructions.

After installing you will be able to run spyder easily.

Hope this Helps.